# How can I execute this Python package?

Tags: python

I found this package of descent gradient optimization variants in python.
I installed python interpreter but i don't know how i can run the package. 
I already tried to use windows cmd.
Ididn't used python before ,thanks a lot for helping me.

[py-optim github](https://github.com/schaul/py-optim)

Comment: Read https://github.com/BurntSushi/nfldb/wiki/Python-&-pip-Windows-installation

Comment: Have you tried running the test files? Maybe with a Python IDE like Spyder or PyCharm

Comment: I read it , this is about setting environement path .

Comment: NO Jessica , i will try it now.

Comment: Can someone reply me if the package in the post ( the link ) is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The github repository lacks a `setup.py`. If you want to install it, add the following code with the name `setup.py` to the top-level folder of the repository on your device. Then add one `__init__.py` file to the folder `..\PyOptim`. The `__init__.py` can be totally empty. Try also to file an issue in the repo, stating that the `setup.py`is missing.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='pyoptim',
      version='0.1',
      description='optimizerTool',
      url='https://github.com/schaul/py-optim',
      author='None',
      packages=['PyOptim',
                'PyOptim.algorithms',
                'PyOptim.benchmarks',
                'PyOptim.core',
                'PyOptim.external_libs'])
```

Afterwards, open a cmd in the top-level folder, and run

```
python setup.py install
```

This installs everything. You then can import everything.

**Note:** This is only a quick- setup.py. Please also add `install-requeries` and so on to install dependencies of the repo.

If you want the folders test and tools also to be installed, add an empty `__init__.py`file to these folders as well and add the names in the `packages` list in the `setup.py`.

**EDIT:** Use [this](https://github.com/FWuellhorst/py-optim) fork of the repository were i added the missing files. Make sure you install `python 2.x` as this repo is not for `3.x`.

Comment: I failed to do this , can you provide me with working package.

Comment: what this the top level folder for you

Comment: https://github.com/FWuellhorst/py-optim
Use this fork. Download the repo, and run `setup.py`as described

Comment: Yes , now how can i run an algorithm

Comment: Thanks a lot f.wue , just i don't know how to run an algorithm like sgd

Comment: As i am not familiar with this package, I  cannot tell you how to do it. Look at the docstrings to check how a function works